# How to dispatch action just when another action will be done, with sagas?

Tags: redux-saga

I have a timeout, which prints `tick` in console with 1000ms delay. This timeout start by action `TICK`. How can I dispatch another action with redux-saga just after timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your saga, lets call it `SagaA` listens to the `TICK` action, you could use an *effect* called `delay`, so the next action will be dispatched with a timeout.

```
function* sagaA() {
   yield take('TICK');
   yield delay(1000);
   yield put(/* your action */); // will be fired 1s after `TICK` was dispatched
}
```